# find a $3 \times 3$ orthogonal matrix $A?$

Tags: linear-algebra

find  a  $3 \times 3$  orthogonal matrix   $A$  whose   first  two  columns  are  $\begin{bmatrix}  \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \\ 0\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \end{bmatrix}$ and  $\begin{bmatrix}  \frac{-1}{\sqrt 3} \\ \frac{-1}{\sqrt 3}\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} \end{bmatrix}?$

**My attempt**  : Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}  \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}&\frac{-1}{\sqrt 3} & a\\ 0& \frac{-1}{\sqrt 3}&b\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}& \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}&c \end{bmatrix}$

According to the definition of orthogonal matrix  we have

$AA^T=1 \implies \begin{bmatrix}  \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}&\frac{-1}{\sqrt 3} & a\\ 0& \frac{-1}{\sqrt 3}&b\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}& \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}&c \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}  \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}&0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\\ \frac{-1}{\sqrt 3}& \frac{-1}{\sqrt 3}&\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\\ a& b&c \end{bmatrix}=I$

$\implies \begin{bmatrix} \frac{5}{6} +a^2 & \frac{1}{3}+ ab & \frac{1}{6} + ac \\\frac{1}{3}+ ab & \frac{1}{3} +b^2 & -\frac{1}{3} +bc \\ \frac{1}{6} +ac & \frac{-1}{3} + bc & \frac{5}{6}  + c^2  \end{bmatrix}=I$

$\implies \frac{5}{6} +a^2=1,\frac{1}{3} +b^2 =1,\frac{5}{6}  + c^2=1$

$ a =c= \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 6}}, b= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{ 3}}$

Therefore  $A=\begin{bmatrix}  \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}&\frac{-1}{\sqrt 3} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 6}}\\ 0& \frac{-1}{\sqrt 3}&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{ 3}}\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}& \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}& \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 6}}\end{bmatrix}$

What do you think, am I right?

Comment: What happens when you do the inner product of the first column and the third one? Are the parameters $a,b$ and $c$ you have chosen the only ones who make the equations true?

Comment: You should look into your choices of signs of a, b and c. You dont have an equality to the identity matrix for your choices.

Comment: okay ,thank you for correcting  my  misunderstanding @Balloon that  means  $a= -1/\sqrt{ 6}$ Am i right

Comment: Column 1 is not orthogonal to column 3 so that is not correct. Here is an alternative method with much less algebra: Pick a random vector which is linearly independent from the other two columns. Then subtract from that vector its orthogonal projections onto the other two vectors and normalize.

Comment: @Chessnerd321 Actually, I don't know how to do that

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the (normalized) cross product of the given vectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out above, you can only conclude (so far) that $|a|=|c|=\frac1{\sqrt6}$ and that $|b|=\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt3}.$

Fortunately, you have three other equations to work with: $$ab=-\frac13\\ac=-\frac16\\bc=\frac13.$$ From these, we can easily see that $b$ and $c$ need the same sign, while $a$ needs a different sign from the other two. Can you see how we know that?

Alternate approaches to this problem include use of the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process), or simply taking a [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of the first two column vectors (since they're both 3-dimensional unit vectors).